# Amazon EC2 port open from inside but closed from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to set up a taskwarrior server on an amazon ec2 instance.

The problem is that the port (53589) is not accecible from the outside.

From the instance, I can telnet to 53589 an Nmap, lsof and netstat all show that everything is in working order.

From the outside I cannot access this port. Nmap shows:

```
Host is up (0.17s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
53589/tcp closed unknown
```

... and telnet shows connection refused.

I have already restarted the instance and the security groups is set to accept any traffic.

Any help?

EDIT:

Linux version:

```
[ec2-user@cs-syd ~]$ uname -a
Linux cs-syd.eu 4.1.13-19.30.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 11 03:42:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

IP tables:

```
[ec2-user@cs-syd ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Depending which version of linux you are using, you may also have iptables or another internal firewall enabled.

Comment: Is your instances in a VPC? Is it in a private subnet or public subnet?

Comment: It sounds like you might have your service listening on 127.0.0.1 rather than 0.0.0.0...

Comment: The issue might be with the instance's security group. Can you explicitly add an 'allow' statement for 'port' 53589 for the entire world, i.e. '0.0.0.0/0'

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Wait, this may be the golden tip. I don't want to have the service listening on `localhost` ? Currently it is.

Comment: You typically want it listening on **all** interfaces.  A service listening *only* on `localhost` is only accessible *(spoiler alert)* from `localhost`, because nobody else can access **your** 127.0.0.1.  On other interfaces, the port will remain closed (unless, of course, a *different* service is listening there, which is unusual but possible).

Comment: Oh dear, Now I feel like an idiot. This is so obvious in hindsight. But now I'm confused. Should I then use `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` when configuring the service? and why have I never had a problem like this before?!

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be problem with your security group rules.If you have opened all ports but there must be a rule over-riding that rule. If want to open all ports for public, then remove all other rules that are present in your security group.
Hope this solves your issue.